# Using a Swift initializer in Objective C with an untyped parameter that adheres to a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm having issues with Xcode 6 automatically bridging my object's initializer, created in swift, to Objective-C. The issue seems to be that I am not defining the parameter of the initializer as having any particular class, but instead define it by adhering to a particular protocol. The custom initializer is written as follows:

```
public init(delegate: <PROTOCOL_NAME>) {
    self.delegate = delegate
    super.init()
}
```

When I write the init method like this, it isn't being accepted in the Objective-C file I'm trying to use it in (i.e. it gets marked with an error, doesn't come up with an autofill suggestion). I've made sure that the protocol I'm referencing is tagged with `@objc`, so I can use it in Objective-C files.

When I create an init method with a single parameter `delegate` that's just an `NSObject`, the Objective-C file immediately accepts a call to `[[OBJECT_NAME alloc] initWithDelegate:(NSObject)]`, so I know that the bridging between Swift and Obj-C is working in my project.

I'm currently using a workaround where I just call the basic `init()` method and set the delegate afterward, but I would really like to know if it is possible to get the convenience initializer with the protocol-conforming `delegate` parameter working in Objective-C.

Comment: Is your swift class a subclass of `NSObject`, or is it pure swift? Since you said you called `[[OBJECT_NAME alloc] initWithDelegate:...]` and `alloc` is in there, I'm assuming it's a subclass of `NSObject`, but it's not clear.

Comment: Yes, the object is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay shortly after starting writing this question I figured out a solution to this issue. It seems like the kinds of things that are bridged over from Swift files to Objective-C are limited (though to what exactly I'm not sure). To solve this particular issue, I made the aforementioned protocol adhere to the `NSObjectProtocol` in Swift. After doing so, the proper init method was automatically ported over to Objective-C.

The code to make the protocol adhere to the `NSObjectProtocol` looks like the following:

```
@objc public protocol <PROTOCOL_NAME>: NSObjectProtocol {
    /* Code and stuff */
}
```

If anyone else has a better idea of what's going on here with respect to Swift-ObjC bridging, please do comment because I'd like to know more.

Comment: You shouldn't need to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`; I believe `@objc` is sufficient. By default, swift protocols are not Objective-C compatible.

Comment: Yeah, seems like you're right. I removed the `NSObjectProtocol` inheritance from my code and built without errors. I thought I had tried doing that before but I must have skipped it.